# Where is Spring Social Etrade extension

Tags: spring, spring-social

On the Spring Social API Providers wiki, there is an Etrade API listed, but no link.  I have searched Google, but only found an empty repository and an old Nexus repo with a jar.  Is there a documented Etrade extension?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/wiki/Api-Providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a list of all APIs for which there is a Spring Social extension. It is a list of several known public APIs. If there's not a link in the 3rd column, then it means that we're unaware of any such extension. Think of that empty last column as an opportunity for you (or someone) to take on the task of creating such an extension.

Note also that the list is not maintained often and probably needs a bit of updating.